# Worktree branches in git show unmerged even after merging

Tags: git, git-branch, git-worktree

I often use `git add worktree wtname` to create separate branches. When I merge the changes on the branch `wtname` to the master, I expect that `git branch --no-merged` should not list `wtname` branch. However, it does. Worse, even after removing the worktree:

```
rm -rf wtname
git worktree remove wtname
```

I can't delete this branch unless I force delete it. After the above written commands, if I run `git branch -d wtname`, it throws the following error:

```
error: The branch 'wtname' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D wtname'.
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: You don't show how you did the merge, but if you used `git merge --squash` or a GitHub PR, there's a good chance that the branch was never actually merged and Git's complaint is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: (just repeating torek's comment) Can you explain how you merged your branch to master ?

Comment: I didn't use squash. I simply merged on master : `git merge wtname`

Comment: I must point out that this happens only if I create branch by adding a separate worktree and not for normal branches.

Comment: “this happens only if I create branch by adding a separate worktree” Yes, but it doesn’t happen at all for other people. Can you provide a sequence of commands allowing the issue to be reproduced?

Answer (score 2):

You have not shown us your real code, but one counterexample is sufficient to disprove the hypothesis, so here is a little playlet in which we create a new branch in a worktree, work on that branch, and merge it — and then remove the worktree and the branch. Whatever you are doing different from this, to the extent of the difference, is likely wrong. Perhaps you are creating the worktree incorrectly? Watch carefully what I do:

```
$ mkdir git
$ cd git
$ git init

$ echo a > a.txt; git add .; git commit -m'a'
$ echo b > a.txt; git add .; git commit -m'b'

$ git worktree add -b br ../br
$ cd ../br

$ echo c > a.txt; git add .; git commit -m'c'
$ echo d > a.txt; git add .; git commit -m'd'
$ cd ../git

$ echo e > e.txt; git add .; git commit -m'e'
$ git merge br

$ git branch --no-merged # nothing
$ git worktree remove br
$ git branch -d br
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I merge the changes on the branch `wtname` to the master

That tops my suspect list. When you let `git worktree add` default-create a branch, it doesn't track anything. When you `git branch -d` a branch, if it doesn't track anything, its safety check is against your current checkout.